# Nokia E71 Jquery not redirecting to facebook login using facebook API

Tags: jquery, facebook, authentication, nokia

i m writing codes for mobile web using Facebook API for facebook login , when i am running the code on iPhone and BlackBerry its working fine redirecting to Facebook Login page and giving me the Json data related to profile in alert Box, but this code is not working for  Nokia E71 mobile by clicking on Login button its not redirecting no event is occurring, somewhere i searched and find Nokia does not support Jquery call,  i have checked using jquery 1.3.2, 1.4.2, 1.7.2,1.5.

so please give me a valuable solution 
thanks